# My variables are not assigned correctly I think

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, trying to make a simple program that runs prime number from 3 to 300 but there seems to be this problem:

```
main.cpp:23:27: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’} and ‘int’)
```

What are the mistakes in my code? I know there's plenty, but I appreciate any support to point them out for me, thanks.

```cpp
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    string prime = "";
    
    for (i = 3; i <= 300; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
            if (i % num == 0) {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 2) {
            prime = prime + i + " ";
        }
    }
    cout << "Prime numbers: ";
    cout << prime;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3):

Look at the error message carefully.  It says that on line 23 you are trying to do an addition operation (`+`) where the left side is a `string` and the right side is an `int`.  You did not post your full code, so I am not sure exactly where line 23 is, but I suspect it is this line:

```
prime = prime + i + " ";
```

Instead of trying to add an integer to a string, you should convert the integer to a string first.  Try something like this:

```
prime = prime + std::to_string(i) + " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can replace line
`prime = prime + i + " ";`
with
`prime = prime +to_string(i)+ " ";`

This problem is occurring since you're trying to add a string to an integer, String should be added to other strings/characters only.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the int variable *i* to a string before concatenating it to *prime*:

```
prime = prime + to_string(i) + " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers show how to use `std::to_string()` to solve the problem.

Another solution is to use `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::string`, let `operator<<` format the `int` to text for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ostringstream prime;

    for (int i = 3; i <= 300; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
            if (i % num == 0) {
                ++counter;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 2) {
            prime << i << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << "Prime numbers: ";
    cout << prime.str();
}
```